# Python: Finding and Pointing to the Midpoint of a string

Tags: python

I just started learning Python (as my first language, so I know next to nothing) and have come across this problem.

Find the midpoint of a word, and point to it using a caret "^".

Example,

```
Computer
   ^
```

Thanks for any tips anyone could give me.

Comment: yeah, so I don't want the exact code. Just point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text='Computer'
print(text)
print('{0:^{1}}'.format('^',len(text)))
```

- `{0:...}` tells `format` to replace replace itself with the first
  argument, `'^'`.
- `{1}` gets replaced by the second argument, `len(text)`.
- `^{1}` tells `format` to center the text, and make the total width
  equal to `len(text)`.

So [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) for the full specs on format.

Comment: This is only going to go to the center of the the text. So it does solve my question, but if I wanted the ^ under say the second to last letter of a word I would have to go about it a different way?

Comment: @apichel: To place the caret under the second-to-last letter, if you could "right-align" the string `'^ '` (a caret followed by a space), or "right-align" a single caret `'^'` with a total width of `len(text)-1`.

Answer (score 8):

Use `len`, which finds the length of the object.

```
>>> x = "Computer"
>>> x[len(x)/2 - 1]
'p'
```

-

```
# a.py
x = "Computer"
print x
print (" " * (len(x)/2 - 1)) + "^"

# % python a.py
Computer
   ^
```

Comment: This is fine for words with an even amount of letters, as the example asks for 'p' over 'u'. However, for an odd amount of letters like in 'catan', this will point to 'a' instead of 't'. `len(x)/2` would be better in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

The mid point depends on odd or even length of a string.
So, if it is an odd length the middle will be exactly len/2+1
if it is an even length, you should decide what is the middle for you (len/2 or len/2+1)

```
x="Computer"

if len(x)%2: return x[len(x)/2+1]

else: return x[len(x)/2]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this format better because it's simple. It just uses the `round()` function. But this is only to find the midpoint and not to execute the `^`, but I assume that should be self-explanatory.

```
my_str2 = "computer"
output = round(len(my_str2)/2)
print(my_str2[output])
```